# Python TwitterAPI issues... ImportError: cannot import name ReadTimeout

Tags: python, twitter, pip

I'm running a code project I've downloaded from Github that uses the TwitterAPI.

I've followed the instructions in the README to install it with

`pip TwitterAPI`

but when I run the python script I'm getting an error that I can't seem to trouble shoot. Apologies... I'm a bit of a Python newb but it looks like requests is installed...

```
$ python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/TwitterAPI/TwitterAPI.py", line 9, in <module>
    from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError, ReadTimeout, SSLError
ImportError: cannot import name ReadTimeout
```

It looks like there's two locations for python libs `/usr/local/lib/` and `/usr/lib/`. I've syslinked the requests lib folder from `/usr/lib/` into `/usr/local/lib/` but this doesn't appear to have fixed the error.

```
$ ll /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
total 584K
drwxr-sr-x 4 root staff 4.0K Jan  5  2015 cffi-0.8.6-py2.7-linux-armv7l.egg
drwxr-sr-x 4 root staff 4.0K Jan  5  2015 cryptography-0.7.1-py2.7-linux-armv7l.egg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff  402 Jan  5  2015 easy-install.pth
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   77K Jan  5  2015 enum34-1.0.4-py2.7.egg
drwxr-sr-x 4 root staff 4.0K Dec 22 23:11 oauthlib
drwxr-sr-x 2 root staff 4.0K Dec 22 23:11 oauthlib-1.0.3.egg-info
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   78K Jan  5  2015 pyasn1-0.1.7-py2.7.egg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  194K Jan  5  2015 pycparser-2.10-py2.7.egg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff 185K Jan  5  2015 pyOpenSSL-0.14-py2.7.egg
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root staff   41 Dec 23 00:14 requests -> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root staff   56 Dec 23 00:14 requests-2.2.1.egg-info -> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-2.2.1.egg-info
drwxr-sr-x 3 root staff 4.0K Dec 22 23:52 requests_oauthlib
drwxr-sr-x 2 root staff 4.0K Dec 22 23:52 requests_oauthlib-0.6.0.dist-info
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff   33 Jan  5  2015 setuptools.pth
drwxr-sr-x 2 root staff 4.0K Dec 22 23:52 TwitterAPI
drwxr-sr-x 2 root staff 4.0K Dec 22 23:52 TwitterAPI-2.3.6.egg-info
```

Comment: If you open the python interpreter and try the command `from requests.exceptions import ReadTimeout` does it work or throw an `ImportError`?

Comment: @wilbur It doesn't look like it:
```>>> from requests.exceptions import ReadTimeout
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name ReadTimeout```

Comment: It looks like there's three versions of Python installed 2.7, 3.3 & 3.4... Could this be causing an issue?

Comment: That could definitely be causing an issue. What is the output when you run `which python`

Comment: ```$  which python
/usr/bin/python```

Comment: ```$ python --version
Python 2.7.6```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you have multiple versions of the requests library installed, and one is a very old version:

See solution here: https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI/issues/46

Take a look into both

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

and delete the requests folder that doesn't end in 2.9.1.

Alternatively you can just delete all `requests*` folders in both locations, and reinstall requests again afterwards.

Comment: ```>>> import requests
>>> print(dir(requests.exceptions))
['BaseHTTPError', 'ChunkedEncodingError', 'ConnectTimeout', 'ConnectionError', 'ContentDecodingError', 'FileModeWarning', 'HTTPError', 'InvalidSchema', 'InvalidURL', 'MissingSchema', 'ProxyError', 'ReadTimeout', 'RequestException', 'RequestsWarning', 'RetryError', 'SSLError', 'StreamConsumedError', 'Timeout', 'TooManyRedirects', 'URLRequired', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__']
>>> print(requests.__version__)
2.9.1```

Comment: ```sudo pip install --upgrade requests
Downloading/unpacking requests from https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/r/requests/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=58a444aaa02780ad01983f5f540e67b2
  Downloading requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (501kB): 501kB downloaded
Installing collected packages: requests
  Found existing installation: requests 2.2.1
    Not uninstalling requests at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, owned by OS
Successfully installed requests
Cleaning up...```

Comment: Thank you... looks like it's in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`. Should I also delete the `requests-2.2.1.egg-info` file in the same folder?

Comment: After deleting the `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests*` I get the following error `ImportError: No module named requests`. Do I need to sysmlink the files from `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests*` into  `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`?

Comment: Perfect... that seems to have fixed the issue. 

I now have a seperate error, basically asking that I should run the script with a newer version of python so that `urllib3` can use a proper SSL object... Do you know how to force a newer version of python?

Comment: try `python3 main.py`

Answer (score 1):

Because you have so many versions of python and requests installed, you should be using [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to create a python environment that exactly matches the complier version and packages you need